# java element XOR in array

Tags: java

I have a problem about the XOR on the element of java array, here is my code:

```
public int[] shuffle() {
    int[] copy = new int[original.length];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0, original.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
        int s = i + (int) (Math.random() * (copy.length - i));
        copy[i] = copy[i] ^ copy[s];
        copy[s] = copy[i] ^ copy[s];
        copy[i] = copy[i] ^ copy[s];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

I just wanna exchange the element in the array.
The result seems so weird, such like[4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0]...I am totally confused about this..

Answer (score 0):

The [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) would be

```
copy[i] = copy[i] ^ copy[s];
copy[s] = copy[s] ^ copy[i];
copy[i] = copy[i] ^ copy[s];
```

**or**

```
copy[i] ^= copy[s];
copy[s] ^= copy[i];
copy[i] ^= copy[s];
```

But I would prefer `Collections.shuffle(List)` and to pass the `int[]` into the method and make it static; like,

```
public static int[] shuffle(int[] original) {
    List<Integer> al = IntStream.of(original).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    return al.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I think I found the reason.. a[index]^a[index]=0. But this is so weird..why the element in array xor itself will produce 0...anyway, I think your solution is better. thank you man

Comment: @Mario_1412 By definition all of the one bits in a number are one. Therefor, if we xor that number with itself **all of the one bits** become zero.